# Is there a better implementation for keeping a count for unique integer pairs?

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable, unordered-map

This is in C++. I need to keep a count for every pair of numbers. The two numbers are of type "int". I sort the two numbers, so (n1 n2) pair is the same as (n2 n1) pair. I'm using the std::unordered_map as the container.

I have been using the elegant [pairing function by Matthew Szudzik, Wolfram Research, Inc.](http://szudzik.com/ElegantPairing.pdf). In my implementation, the function gives me a unique number of type "long" (64 bits on my machine) for every pair of two numbers of type "int". I use this long as my key for the unordered_map (std::unordered_map). Is there a better way to keep count of such pairs? By better I mean, faster and if possible with lesser memory usage.

Also, I don't need all the bits of long. Even though you can assume that the two numbers can range up to max value for 32 bits, I anticipate the max possible value of my pairing function to require at most 36 bits. If nothing else, at least is there a way to have just 36 bits as key for the unordered_map? (some other data type)

I thought of using bitset, but I'm not exactly sure if the std::hash will generate a unique key for any given bitset of 36 bits, which can be used as key for unordered_map.

I would greatly appreciate any thoughts, suggestions etc.

Comment: How about a `std::set` of length 2 for each pair? That way the order is not important.

Comment: So the input is Unsigned?

Comment: Alright, and use the set as key for unordered_map?

Comment: Input can be anything. Positive integers. I've been using int, but unsigned int will also work.

Comment: `long` - don't rely on the machine, use more concrete types, e.g.: `uint64_t`

Comment: Thanks. I understand that such concrete types would solve just portability issues. I will use it.

Comment: Question: do you know all the pairs of integers you need to keep a count for at the beginning? Or can new pairs of integers be inserted at any time?

Comment: @NirFriedman, I do not know all the pairs of integers at the beginning. Any new pair can occur during run time. Anyway, what if I knew, what then?

Comment: Then this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function#Minimal_perfect_hash_function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I think you came with wrong assumption. For `std::unordered_map` and `std::unordered_set` hash does not have to be unique (and it cannot be in principle for data types like `std::string` for example), there should be low probability that 2 different keys will generate the same hash value. But if there is a collision it would not be end of the world, just access would be slower. I would generate 32bit hash from 2 numbers and if you have an idea of typical values just test for probability of hash collision and choose hash function accordingly.

For that to work you should use pair of 32bit numbers as a key in `std::unordered_map` and provide a proper hash function. Calculating unique 64bit key and use it with hash map is controversal as hash_map will then calculate another hash of this key, so it is possible you are making it slower.

About 36 bits key, this is not a good idea unless you have a special CPU that handles 36 bit data. Your data either will be aligned on 64bit boundary and you would not have any benefits of saving memory, or you will get penalty of unaligned data access otherwise. In first case you would just have extra code to get 36 bits from 64bit data (if processor supports it). In the second your code will be slower than 32 bit hash even if there are some collisions.

If that hash_map is a bottleneck you may consider different implementation of hash map like goog-sparsehash.sourceforge.net

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I wanted it to be unique so that I could just use the unordered_map. If it's not unique, then I should implement my own table, correct? Or am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: @learningToCode updated answer, no you do not need to reimplement unordered_map

Comment: thanks a lot. That's really interesting and not obvious to me.  If my hash generates the same key for two different inputs (however low probability), and lets call the key 'K' of type (uint32_t). Say I have it as std::unordered_map<uint32_t, int> table. I have been using it as table[K]++ to increment count. So, I don't see how the resolution of two distinct pairs mapped to K can be possible. I will look it up, but if it's something simple, please let me know or redirect me to it and thanks a lot.

Comment: @learningToCode you misunderstand the concept of hash map. Key in the map should be pair of numbers, not the hash. Hash function specified separately, and actually does not really matter if it produces 64 or 32 bits as hash is not stored in the map. If you really want to save space you need to find a way to pack that pair into 32bits uniquely, 36bits would not save the room neither increase speed, unless you find CPU that natively works with 36bits, which I doubt.

Comment: @learningToCode sorry did not fully understand your question originally and missed the part that you use 64bit as a key. Updated answer.

Comment: thank you. I wasn't aware that I could customize the hash function of the unordered_map. For some reason, I just assumed that if I wanted to map two numbers, I would have to generate some unique key as an index for the hash map. I'll look into specifying hash functions directly. That way I think I could generate a 32 bit and hopefully it can handle collisions. Thanks! Let me know if I'm missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents, the pairing functions that you've got in the article are WAY more complicated than you actually need. Mapping 2 32 bit UNISIGNED values to 64 uniquely is easy. The following does that, and even handles the non-pair states, without hitting the math peripheral too heavily (if at all).

```
uint64_t map(uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    uint64_t x = a+b;
    uint64_t y = abs((int32_t)(a-b));

    uint64_t ans = (x<<32)|(y);
    return ans;
}

void unwind(uint64_t map, uint32_t* a, uint32_t* b)
{
  uint64_t x = map>>32;
  uint64_t y = map&0xFFFFFFFFL;

  *a = (x+y)>>1;
  *b = (x-*a);
}
```

Another alternative:

```
uint64_t map(uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
  bool bb = a>b;
    uint64_t x = ((uint64_t)a)<<(32*(bb));
    uint64_t y = ((uint64_t)b)<<(32*!(bb));

    uint64_t ans = x|y;
    return ans;
}

void unwind(uint64_t map, uint32_t* a, uint32_t* b)
{

  *a = map>>32;
  *b = map&0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

That works as a unique key. You can easily modify that to be a hash function provider for unordered map, though whether or not that will be faster than std::map is dependent on the number of values you've got.

NOTE: this will fail if the values a+b > 32 bits.

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought of that. Just curious why you need to add and subtract the two numbers and not just shift one to first 32 bits and the next number as the other 32 bits of the 64 bit number?

Comment: @learningToCode I wanted to both avoid branching and capture the fact that (a,b)==(b,a). Also I have a tendency to over-think things. Provided an alternate that should do just what you suggested without branching, and is probably just as fast, though you'd have to measure it.

Comment: Thanks for your time. This is my first day on stackoverflow as a member. I'm learning quite a lot. Thanks!